# Navigating though a json using JSONP, can a number be returned as a JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, inheritance, jsonp

I'm writing a function that navigates though a json given its coordinates. For example:

```
{
 "a": {
    "b" : "c"
 },
 "d": {
   ...
 }
}
```

If I call

```
NavigateThroughJson("a.b", myJsonObject)
```

I should get `"c"` as the output. I'm doing this because I can't use deserialization, the json has an arbitrary format. Here is my function:

```
public JsonValue NavigateThroughJson(String coordinates, JsonObject jsonObject) {
    JsonObject o = jsonObject;
    String[] nodes = coordinates.split("\\.");//Splits the dot
    for (String node: nodes) {
        node = node.replace("\"", ""); //Removes "" from the keys
        o = o.getJsonObject(node);
    }
    return o;
}
```

The problem is that when I try this for the following json (and call NavigateThroughJson("high", jsonAbove)):

```
{"high":7999.0,"vol":1261.83821469,"buy":7826.01,"last":7884.0,...}
```

nothing is returned, it's like `o.getJsonObject(...)` returned nothing, not even `null`.

I think this happens because "high" points to a Number and not really a json object like `high: {...}`, even though a consistent library should return `7999.0` as a JsonObject with the `Type` `Number`. As you can see, `JsonObject` implements `JsonValue`, which can have types such as `String`, `Number`, etc. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.html

However, since a jsonObject also implements `Map<String, JsonValue>`, I can get the number when I do `map.get("high")` for example, but I don't think this is the right way to do it and if "high" points to another `JsonValue` that is not a `Number` (it's a json block `{}` for example), then I need to treat this `JsonValue` as a `Map<String, JsonValue>`, but casting is not the best thing to do.

**UPDATE**:

There seems to be a bug with this library. Remember that the json keys are strings with "", so if I try:

```
    System.out.println(jsonObject.getJsonObject("high"));
    System.out.println("hello?");
```

It won't print anything, not even `"hello?"` which is above!!! However, if I do:

```
    System.out.println(jsonObject.getJsonObject("\"high\""));
    System.out.println("hello?");
```

The `"hello?"` is printed, but the print above it is `"null"` even though I'm **sure** that the key `"high"` (with "") exists because I printed the `jsonObject` before.

Comment: Also, does anyone have any clue in how to read the json without the "" in the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json have 4 primarily type: Object, Array, number and string these type corresponding to: Map, List, BigDecimal and String in java type. So that for each type of object you must call to the right function: `getJsonObject`, `getJsonArray`, `getJsonNumber` or `getJsonString`. You can not getJsonObject on a JsonNumber, so that cause your error.

For your case, you can not deserialize your json, so I propose to you my solution is parse it to a Map, then loop throw this map to get value you want. Here is an [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44349882/4039840) for this.

Comment: Makes sense, I thought Numbers, Strings, etc, could be seen as JsonObjects as well

Comment: Also, there's no method "instanceOf"

Comment: Also, you're comparing to see if JsonObject is a number, a list, etc, but at this stage it is really a JsonObject. I should see if the value of the key "high" is a Number, a List, etc, but for that I need to get it first, but how?

Comment: @LucasZanella For a quick response I have wrong in syntax about "instanceOf", I have edited answer for a complete solution for you.